# iOS Keyboard Extension: Memoji like paste

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard, ios-stickers, memoji

Apples build in Emoji Keyboard has a section with "Memoji" stickers.
If you tap on any of these stickers (it seems to be a PNG image), then it's automatically inserted into the textfield or into the chat of the current App, for example WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger or iMessage.

[image: WhatsApp with Memoji]

Is it possible to get the same functionality with a custom keyboard? Or is Apple using some private API for the Memoji stickers?

I know how to add an image or image data to the pasteboard like UIPasteboard.general.image or UIPasteboard.general.setData(...). But if I do so, the png image isn't pasted automatically into the textfield. The user has to do additional steps and tap with the finger into the textfield and select "paste".

Comment: Have you found the solution? And have you managed to send a sticker and not a normal image?

Answer (score 0):

All the mentioned apps use UITextView, upon selection of any sticker the OS adds this image as an NSTextAttachment to the attributedString of the text view

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the “selection of any sticker” is some kind of private API?

Comment: Yeah, there's no direct access to selection from the keyboard. However, you're able to pull the image from the UITextView once inserted to reuse it however you wish. I actually mention how I accomplish this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67646151/2363439