# Using Animoji/Memoji as profile photo

Tags: swift, memoji

I am building a profile section in my app. I want to enable the selection of Animoji/MeMoji for a profile picture (exactly like the contacts app permits as shown in the image here). [image]

Does anyone know if apple is planning to release an API for this or where I could find more information for building this functionality into our app? I think this would be a nice feature for our users.

Answer (score 2):

I have built very similar functionality in my application. I must say, it's one of my favorite things! There's no official API to this however, I've been able to accomplish a workaround to getting this to work by:

1. Adding a textview which automatically sets in focus in viewWillAppear, and setting its alpha to zero
2. Enabling `allowsEditingTextAttributes` on the textview to ensure the Memoji stickers show up in the keyboard
3. Added a label describing how to get to the stickers for users
4. On sticker selection the textViewDidChange delegate function is called, the OS adds an NSTextAttachment with the image.
5. Once I get the image from the NSTextAttachment, I set it to an image view I have on the screen and reset the text on the textview

And you're done :D

Comment: Hi @NSDavidObject, do you happened to know how to implement this on flutter??